# Modifying the contents of only one Text View programmatically

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a row of 7 Text views a to g. Above them 2 empty Text views. I tap on one of the 7 letters and then one of the two empty ones. At present the letter tapped displays in both the text views in the above row.

What I would like to happen is to display the chosen letter only in the text view that I tap, not in both.
In the end I will have may rows of empty views and I need only one at a time to react to the change.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code I use:

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View{
        @State private var chosenLetter = ""
        @State private var placedLetter = ""
        
        var body: some View{
            VStack {
                HStack {
                Text(self.placedLetter)
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                    self.placedLetter.isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter = "")
                   if !self.placedLetter.isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                }// .onTapGesture(count: 1)
                    Text(self.placedLetter)
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    //.offset(x: -7, y: 0)
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                     self.placedLetter.isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter = "")
                    if !self.placedLetter.isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                    }// .onTapGesture(count: 1)
                    Text(self.placedLetter)
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.placedLetter.isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter = "")
                       if !self.placedLetter.isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                    }// .onTapGesture(count: 1)
                }// HStack
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                HStack {
                    Text("a")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "a"
                    }
                    Text("b")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "b"
                    }
                    Text("c")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "c"
                    }
                    Text("d")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "d"
                    }
                    Text("e")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "e"
                    }
                    Text("f")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "f"
                    }
                    Text("g")
                        .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                            self.chosenLetter = "g"
                    }
                }// HStack
            }.padding()//.font(.headline)
        }
    }
    struct CustomTextBorder: ViewModifier {
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            return content
                .font(Font.custom("Courier", size: 16))
                .padding(10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                )
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: You can use a dictionary which manages the rows and columns.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var chosenLetter = ""
    var rows = 3
    var columns = 3
    @State var dict: Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, String>> = [:]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<rows, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.columns, id: \.self) { column in
                        Text(self.dict[row]?[column] ?? "")
                            .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                                if let _ = self.dict[row] {
                                    self.dict[row]?[column] = self.chosenLetter
                                } else {
                                    self.dict[row] = [column: self.chosenLetter]
                                }
                                self.chosenLetter = ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
        }
    }
}
```

---

You cannot use a single string State object to bind with 3 text fields to achieve that. You should either use multiple string objects or an array of string. Here is a minimal example of how you can achieve this using an Array of strings. You might wanna make it more dynamic so that array indices are not static.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var chosenLetter = ""
    @State private var placedLetter = ["", "", ""]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(self.placedLetter[0])
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.placedLetter[0].isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter[0] = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter[0] = "")
                        if !self.placedLetter[0].isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                }
                Text(self.placedLetter[1])
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.placedLetter[1].isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter[1] = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter[1] = "")
                        if !self.placedLetter[1].isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                }
                Text(self.placedLetter[2])
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.placedLetter[2].isEmpty ?  (self.placedLetter[2] = self.chosenLetter): (self.placedLetter[2] = "")
                        if !self.placedLetter[2].isEmpty {self.chosenLetter = ""}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, make sure the code you post on SO has proper indentation and no unwanted comments. It helps the reader to easily understand the question.

Comment: Thank you Ishmet that works well.However, I have 225 text views on screen in a grid 15 by 15. I am stuck for a better way to recognize them without having to paste the code 225 times and change the number of each. Is there a way to assign a unique id to each of them while they are built so that it is returned when tapped? Sorry being a pain but English is not my first language and all my searches so far returned no result.

Comment: Hi Ishmeet, thanks again for the update. Unfortunately I cannot make it work. I placed an a in the first row of the first(left) column and I was unable to place any more letters in the same row. All three rows behave like that. Sometimes it is also not possible to clear a letter on the first tap and one time I cleared a letter and they all disappeared. I notice you do not use the placedLetter in your ForEach. May this be part of it?

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code. I would not be able to say why it's not working for you without looking at the code.

Comment: I posted the code above Ishmeet. Only one letter is accepted on each row.

Comment: @MarianoGiovanniMarioLeonti Sorry, my bad. I have fixed my code above. The `if let` condition inside `tapGesture` was incorrect. I have fixed the condition and not it should work as expected

Comment: Thanks Ishmeet, problem solved.  I can move on with the job now!

Comment: @MarianoGiovanniMarioLeonti please accept this as answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the correct way of answering your question Ishmeet, the code was too long for a comment.

Here is the code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTextBorder: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
            .fixedSize()
            .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
            .font(Font.custom("Courier", size: 18))
            .padding(7)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
        )
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var chosenLetter = ""
    var rows = 3
    var columns = 3
    @State var dict: Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, String>> = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<rows, id: \.self) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<self.columns, id: \.self) { column in
                        Text(self.dict[row]?[column] ?? "")
                            .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                            .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                                if let outer = self.dict[row] {
                                    if let _ = outer[column] {
                                        self.dict[row]?[column] = self.chosenLetter
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    self.dict[row] = [column: self.chosenLetter]
                                }
                                self.chosenLetter = ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            HStack {
                Text("a")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "a"
                }
                Text("b")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "b"
                }
                Text("c")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "c"
                }
                Text("d")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "d"
                }
                Text("e")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "e"
                }
                Text("f")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "f"
                }
                Text("g")
                    .modifier(CustomTextBorder())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 1) {
                        self.chosenLetter = "g"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```